# Error converting VB code to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

***Hello i have  a problem to convert vb to c sharp***

```
Dim Query As String = "UPDATE F_Shqip SET Lika_Sh=@Fjalet_Sh WHERE Id_Sh=@Id_Sh"
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Query, con)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lika_Sh", Trim(Me.txbLikaSh.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Sh", Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem(0).ToString)
```

**In c sharp:**

```
string Query = "UPDATE F_Shqip SET Lika_Sh=@Lika_Sh WHERE Id_Sh=@Id_Sh";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);

//two lines with errors
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lika_Sh", Strings.Trim(this.txbLikaSh.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Sh", this.ListBox1.SelectedItem(0).ToString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Listbox` has just one selected item, change your code to;

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Sh", this.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString);
```

If your `Listbox` has multiple selected item and your `SelectionMode` is `MultiExtended`, you can use [`ListBox.SelectedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindices.aspx) instead like;

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Sh", this.ListBox1.SelectedIndices[0].ToString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `this.ListBox1.SelectedItem[0]` instead of `this.ListBox1.SelectedItem(0)`
C# uses square brackets for arrays, but VB.NET uses parentheses for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lika_Sh", Strings.Trim(this.txbLikaSh.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Sh", this.ListBox1.SelectedItem(0).ToString);
```

Try this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lika_Sh", this.txbLikaSh.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Sh", this.ListBox1.SelectedItem[0].ToString());
```

The following links may be useful:

[CodeProject - Complete Comparison for VB.NET and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9978/Complete-Comparison-for-VB-NET-and-C)

[Wikipedia - Comparison of C Sharp and Visual Basic .NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Visual_Basic_.NET)

Code converters:

[DeveloperFusion - Convert VB.NET to C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

[DeveloperFusion - Convert C# to VB.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Comment: You should also use "this.txbLikaSh.Text.Trim()" instead of the Microsoft.VisualBasic function.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: you're right, my mistake. It's fixed now.